# Are there any other references to Gang Starr lyrics in Luke Cage dialog?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, luke-cage

*All* of the Luke Cage season 1 episode titles are Gang Starr song titles.

In season 1, episode 9 "DWYCK", there is a scene where the police psychologist evaluating Misty Knight gives her a can of lemonade, and the following dialog occurs:

> Psychologist: It was a popular drink.
>
> Misty: And it still is.

This is a *direct* reference to the lyric

> Lemonade was a popular drink, and it still is

from the Gang Starr song [DWYCK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2X5OJiyaYz4#t=02m02s).

**Are there any other bits of dialog in any episode of Luke Cage that is a direct reference to a lyric in the Gang Starr song that the episode is named after?**

What about near direct quotes of lyrics in the dialog, even if it's *not* the song that the episode was named after?

Comment: Gotta be.  People who grew up then and listened to hip hop remember that song - and particularly that line.  Something about the way it flowed was just nice

Comment: @user1167442 exactly.  Woulda been awesome if they had Diamondback (or Shades maybe?) say: "You could say I'm sorta the boss, so get lost."

Comment: Or - he could say 'Clips are inserted into my gun...never have to run'

Comment: This lyric is also referenced in the Boondocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I can finally answer this question definitively, because I went to an advance screening of episodes 1 & 2 from Luke Cage Season 2 the other night, and the showrunner, Cheo Hodari Coker, was there, so I was able to ask him personally.

Aaaand... the answer is no.  He said that that was the only lyric he worked into the story.